# Are there any alternatives to the Python csv module that can quote newlines and use arbitrary characters as newlines for reading?

Tags: python, csv, newline

Python's `csv` module is hard-coded (in C) to immediately recognize a carriage return/line feed as an end of a row when using the reader.

In many cases, I've had to write a script (in Python, because tools like `sed` do not treat newlines/carriage returns normally) to replace in-cell newlines byte-by-byte with an unused text character (vertical tab) and then replace that when parsing it again with a csv reader.

There are two primary cases I have had to deal with:

- The true "end-of-line" was always indicated by `\r\n` and in-cell newlines were simply `\n`
- The end-of-lines were all `\n`, except when within a quoted field. (e.g., `val1,"first line of cell\nsecond line of cell",val3`)

The files I am dealing with are too large to efficiently process in memory, so I would like to know if there's an alternative parser that doesn't automatically terminate a row after a carriage return or newline is encountered.

Comment: Why would you have in-cell newlines in a csv?  Seems like you should be using excel.

Comment: I am reading data downloaded from the internet and processing it within a Python program. There are 40+ of these files, arbitrarily large, change monthly, and are on a headless Ubuntu server.

Comment: How large is "large"? Also, isn't Windows new-line `\r\n`?

Comment: Large can be > 1 GB, but I may want to extend this code to files that can be > 10 GB. That entirely depends on what data my code may need to process in the future.

Comment: Also, you are correct about the `\r\n` newline, although that difference doesn't affect the general problem.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I just tested on a Mac with a 50MB CVS downloaded from Stack Overflow's own database, and the `csv` module works as expected, both with the original line endings (`\n` inside a cell, `\r\n` outside) and with all CRs normalized to just `\n`.

Comment: The problem isn't necessarily the end-of-line characters. Those are a problem when I use other means/tools to process the files to make them more readable by Python's csv module, since it would require regular expressions, which usually require some sort of newline delimiter (I think it's fixed on `sed` for Mac, at least) in order to avoid scanning the entire file.

Comment: Please add a sample CSV file that you're unable to parse (preferably just a couple lines and not several GBs).

Comment: You could use something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to put sample data in and post a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `csv` module that's getting your line endings wrong - it's the `file` object. The csv reader just treats its first argument as an iterator. The `file` object treats all styles of line endings as line terminators by default. For Python 3, you can solve your issue by opening your csv file with the argument `newline='\r\n'`:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('weird.csv', newline='\r\n'))
```

With Python 2, you can use the `io` module:

```
import io
reader = csv.DictReader(io.open('weird.csv', newline='\r\n'))
```

Note that both these approaches count on the newline-containing field being properly quoted. If it's not, you can try wrapping your open file (with either approach above) with a generator that quotes the newline-containing fields, like so:

```
import re
def quote(fh, delimiter='\t'):
    for line in fh:
        # using line.strip('\r\n') could improperly remove a
        # leading or trailing \n character
        fields = re.sub('\r\n$', '', line).split(delimiter)
        quoted = []
        for field in fields:
            if '\n' in field and not re.match('".*"$', field, re.MULTILINE):
                # must quote any existing quotes!
                field = '"{}"'.format(field.replace('"', '""')
            quoted.append(field)
        yield delimiter.join(quoted) + '\r\n'

reader = csv.DictReader(quote(io.open('weird.csv', newline='\r\n')), delimiter='\t')
```